# Remove duplicate rows comparing multiple columns and conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with following columns.

```
CUI1        CUI2        RELA    SL          CUI_x       SAB_x  CODE_x     STR_x               TTY_x CUI_y       SAB_y       CODE_y      STR_y                   TTY_y
C0010356    C0205721    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0010356    MDR    10011409   Cross infection     PT    C0205721    MDR         10029803    Nosocomial infection    PT
C0205721    C0010356    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0205721    MDR    10029803   Nosocomial infection PT   C0010356    MDR         10011409    Cross infection         PT
C0010356    C0205721    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0010356    MDR    10011409   Cross infection     LLT   C0205721    MDR         10029803    Nosocomial infection    PT
C0205721    C0010356    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0205721    MDR    10029803   Nosocomial infection PT   C0010356    MDR         10011409    Cross infection         LLT
```

I would like to compare rows if the value of "CODE_x" and "CODE_y" are interchangeable in multiple rows at the same TTY_x and TTY_y level, consider only one row.

The expected output is:

```
CUI1        CUI2        RELA    SL          CUI_x       SAB_x  CODE_x     STR_x               TTY_x CUI_y       SAB_y       CODE_y      STR_y                   TTY_y
C0010356    C0205721    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0010356    MDR    10011409   Cross infection     PT    C0205721    MDR         10029803    Nosocomial infection    PT
C0205721    C0010356    same_as SNOMEDCT_US C0205721    MDR    10029803   Nosocomial infection PT   C0010356    MDR         10011409    Cross infection         LLT
```

I do not have a starting point for this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not make a new column where you add CODE_x and CODE_y, either as a string in order (eg. "lowestNumber_highestNumber") or as the sum of both (depending on the source of the values and if this could lead to false "matches"). You can the use `df.drop_duplicates()`, considering only the new column and TTY_x and TTY_y. ]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you both need to check the equality of TTY_x/TTY_y and the duplicated status of the CUI1/CUI2:

```
# is this a common TTY?
m1 = df['TTY_x'].eq(df['TTY_y'])
# are the CUI values duplicated when order doesn't matter?
m2 = df[['CUI1', 'CUI2']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()

out = df[~(m1&m2)]
```

Output:

```
       CUI1      CUI2     RELA           SL     CUI_x SAB_x    CODE_x            STR_x TTY_x     CUI_y SAB_y    CODE_y                 STR_y TTY_y
0  C0010356  C0205721  same_as  SNOMEDCT_US  C0010356   MDR  10011409  Cross infection    PT  C0205721   MDR  10029803  Nosocomial infection    PT
```

#### edit

Do you want:

```
# are the TTY values duplicated when order doesn't matter?
m1 = df[['TTY_x', 'TTY_y']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()
# are the CUI values duplicated when order doesn't matter?
m2 = df[['CUI1', 'CUI2']].agg(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()

out = df[~(m1&m2)]
```

Comment: I edited the dataframe. The value in TTY_x and TTY_y not necessarily identical all the time.

Comment: @rshar so using which criterion do you perform the match?

Comment: Value in "CODE_x" and "CODE_y" are duplicated as well as "TTY_x" and "TTY_y" are duplicated

Comment: can you check the edit?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the same but it's not working.

Comment: @rshar then can you be **explicit** in describing what **is not working**, otherwise I'll have to guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250253/discussion-between-rshar-and-mozway).